# List child parents from multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've been on this for two days now and I'm completely stuck. Google and SO couldn't help me further and I'm overlooking something....

This is what I want

```
Home
Typography
404 Page not found
The company
The company/Team
The company/Team/Rick
The company/Team/Rick/Opleiding
The company/Team//Rob
The company/Office
The company/Office/Contact
The company/Office/Route
```

This is my array

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 55
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => Home
            [sub] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 27
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => Typography
            [sub] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 56
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => 404 Page not found
            [sub] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 68
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => The company
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 73
                            [parent_id] => 68
                            [title] => Team
                            [sub] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 74
                                            [parent_id] => 73
                                            [title] => Rick
                                            [sub] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 79
                                                            [parent_id] => 74
                                                            [title] => Opleiding
                                                            [sub] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 75
                                            [parent_id] => 73
                                            [title] => Rob
                                            [sub] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 76
                            [parent_id] => 68
                            [title] => Office
                            [sub] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 78
                                            [parent_id] => 76
                                            [title] => Contact
                                            [sub] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 77
                                            [parent_id] => 76
                                            [title] => Route
                                            [sub] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This is what I have so far

```
public function BuildTitle($array, &$parents = null)
    {
        $html = '';
        foreach($array as $page)
        {
            if($page['parent_id'] != 0)
            {
                $html .= $parents.'/'.$page['title'].'<br/>';
                $parents = $parents.'/'.$page['title'];
            }
            else
            {
                $html .= $page['title'].'<br/>';
                $parents = $page['title'];
            }

            $html .= $this->BuildTitle($page['sub'], $parents);
        }
        return $html;
    }
```

And that returns

```
Home
Typography
404 Page not found
The company
The company/Team
The company/Team/Rick
The company/Team/Rick/Opleiding
The company/Team/Rick/Opleiding/Rob
The company/Team/Rick/Opleiding/Rob/Office
The company/Team/Rick/Opleiding/Rob/Office/Contact
The company/Team/Rick/Opleiding/Rob/Office/Contact/Route
```

Parent/child relations are unlimited. What am I doing wrong/missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're modifying the same `$parents` value in every iteration. So, as long as the parent isn't 0, it just appends the current child to whatever the path is.

Imagine for instance you had the following scenario:

```
foo
   bar
   baz
```

When processing `foo`, it'd start with `$parents = 'foo'`.
It then goes through each of the children, updating `$parents`:

- `bar` makes `$parents = $parents . '/' . $page['title'] = 'foo' . '/' . 'bar' = 'foo/bar'`.
- `baz` makes `$parents = $parents . '/' . $page['title'] = 'foo/bar' . '/' . 'bar' = 'foo/bar/baz'`.

What you want is this:

```
public function BuildTitle($array, $parents = null)
    {
        $html = '';
        foreach($array as $page)
        {
            if($page['parent_id'] != 0)
            {
                $html .= $parents.'/'.$page['title'].'<br/>';
                $new_parents = $parents.'/'.$page['title'];
            }
            else
            {
                $html .= $page['title'].'<br/>';
                $new_parents = $page['title'];
            }

            $html .= $this->BuildTitle($page['sub'], $new_parents);
        }
        return $html;
    }
```

Comment: You sir are awesome! I only tried to change the $parents var but never thought of passing a new var. Thanks!